# Update multiple columns by loop?

Tags: sql, loops

I have a select statement which I want to convert into an update statement for all the columns in the table which have the name `Variable[N]`.

For example, I want to do these things:

1. I want to be able to convert the SQL below into an update statement.
2. I have `n` columns with the name `variable[N]`. The example below only updates column `variable63`, but I want to dynamically run the update on all columns with names `variable1` through `variableN` without knowing how many `variable[N]` columns I have in advance. Also, in the example below I get the updated result into `NewCol`. I actually want to update the respective variable column with the results if possible, `variable63` in my example below.

I want to have a wrapper that loops over column `variable1` through `variableN` and perform the same respective update operation on all those columns:

```
SELECT  
     projectid
    ,documentid
    ,revisionno
    ,configurationid
    ,variable63
    ,ISNULL(Variable63, 
            (SELECT TOP 1 
             variable63 
             FROM table1 
             WHERE 
                 documentid = t.documentid 
             and projectid=t.projectid
             and configurationid=t.configurationid 
             and cast(revisionno as int) < cast(t.revisionno as int) 
             AND Variable63 is NOT NULL 
             ORDER BY 
              projectid desc
             ,documentid desc
             ,revisionno desc
             ,configurationid desc
             )) as NewCol
FROM    table1 t;
```

Comment: You will need to use dynamic SQL.  I hope you don't expect it to be fast.

Comment: At least show us what the update statement for variable1 and variable2 would look like... it is hard to know exactly what you are going for here.

Comment: DB is MSSQL 2008 (express version). I do not expect it to be fast. I do t one time as part of migration process which will take long time (few days). I do not necessrily need the update, I can live with select into a new column, but I want to dynamically generate a newcol1 through newcal63 through newcolN. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

There's no general way to loop through variables in SQL, you're supposed to know exactly what you want to modify. In some databases, it will be possible to query system tables to dynamically build an update statement (I know how to do that in InterBase and it's decessor Firebird), but you haven't told us anything which database engine you're using.

Below is a way you could update several fields that are null, COALESCE and CASE are two way of doing the same thing, as is using LEFT JOIN or NOT EXISTS. Use the ones you and your database engine is most comfortable with. Beware that all records will be updated, so this is not a good solution if your database contains millions of records, each record is large and you want this query to be executed lots of times.

```
UPDATE table1 t
SET t.VARIABLE63 = 
  COALESCE(t.VARIABLE63, 
           (SELECT VARIABLE63
            FROM table1 t0
            LEFT JOIN table1 tNot 
                   ON tNot.documentid = t.documentid
                  AND tNot.projectid=t.projectid        
                  AND tNot.configurationid=t.configurationid
                  AND cast(tNot.revisionno as int) > cast(t0.revisionno as int)
                  AND cast(tNot.revisionno as int) < cast(t.revisionno as int)
                  AND tNot.Variable63 is NOT NULL
            WHERE t0.documentid = t.documentid
              AND t0.projectid=t.projectid        
              AND t0.configurationid=t.configurationid
              AND cast(t0.revisionno as int) < cast(t.revisionno as int)
              AND t0.Variable63 is NOT NULL
              AND tNot.Variable63 is NULL)),
    t.VARIABLE64 = CASE WHEN t.VARIABLE64 IS NOT NULL then t.VARIABLE64
                        ELSE (SELECT VARIABLE64
                              FROM table1 t0
                              WHERE t0.documentid = t.documentid
                                AND t0.projectid=t.projectid        
                                AND t0.configurationid=t.configurationid
                                AND cast(t0.revisionno as int) < cast(t.revisionno as int)
                                AND t0.Variable64 is NOT NULL
                                AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                                               FROM table1 tNot 
                                               WHERE tNot.documentid = t.documentid
                                                 AND tNot.projectid=t.projectid        
                                                 AND tNot.configurationid=t.configurationid
                                                 AND cast(tNot.revisionno as int) > cast(t0.revisionno as int)
                                                 AND cast(tNot.revisionno as int) < cast(t.revisionno as int)
                                                 AND tNot.Variable64 is NOT NULL)) END
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I got it. Function that loops through columns and runs an update command per column.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000),
@cn NVARCHAR(1000)--,
--@r NVARCHAR(1000),
--@start INT

DECLARE col_names CURSOR FOR
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'PIVOT_TABLE'
ORDER BY ordinal_position

--SET @start = 0
DECLARE @op VARCHAR(max)
SET @op=''

OPEN col_names FETCH next FROM col_names INTO @cn

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --print @cn
    IF UPPER(@cn)<> 'DOCUMENTID' and UPPER(@cn)<> 'CONFIGURATIONID' and UPPER(@cn)<> 'PROJECTID' and UPPER(@cn)<> 'REVISIONNO'
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'UPdate pt
        set pt.' + @cn + ' = ((SELECT TOP 1 t.' + @cn + ' FROM pivot_table t WHERE t.documentid = pt.documentid and t.projectid=pt.projectid
        and t.configurationid=pt.configurationid and cast(t.revisionno as int) < cast(pt.revisionno as int) AND t.' + @cn + ' is NOT NULL 
        ORDER BY revisionno desc)) from PIVOT_TABLE pt where pt.' + @cn + ' is NULL;'
        EXEC Sp_executesql
        @sql
        --print @cn
    END
    FETCH next FROM col_names INTO @cn
END

CLOSE col_names
DEALLOCATE col_names;
```